# C# Wpf LifeChart , ToolTip

Tags: c#

Всем привет, кто может подсказать, что это за свойство и как эти значения можно достать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Andrew в коде я имею ввиду отловить, это свойство ToolTip, я прост не могу найти его

Comment: @Andrew исправил вопрос

Comment: Предполагаю что это свойство у ТОЧКИ ( ChartPoint ) - рыскай в этом направлении в интернете. А еще никогда не вставляй код картинкой, пожалуста

Comment: @Andrew понял спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, есть свойство DataTooltip и в нем уже лежат все Points